# How to configure Spring XD to connect remote Gemfire

Tags: spring-xd

I had configured the Spring-XD, application context.xml to connect to remote gemfire db. I am unable to connect to remote DB.  It goes and  connect to local gemfire which comes as part of Spring XD installation. Please can anyone assist what must be wrong.

```
Configuration to disable local gemfire and configure to connect remote : 
/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/xd/config/modules/modules.yml

gemfire:

   useLocator: true

   host: remote-ip-address

   port: 44444

**Configuration to remote connection gemfire - spring-module.xml**

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.data.gemfire.GemfireTemplate">
        <property name="region" ref="restaurants" />
    </bean>

    <util:properties id="gemfire-props">
        <prop key="log-level">warning</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <gfe:cache properties-ref="gemfire-props" />

    <gfe:cache-server bind-address="localhost" port="44444" />

    <gfe:replicated-region id="restaurants">
    </gfe:replicated-region>

When we deploy custom moudules and run it on spring-xd shell which access and store object in gemfire template it goes and saves it in local gmefire instead of remote gemfire database.  Please can anyone guide or suggest right way of confuguring gemfire db.

Regards,
Cleophus P.
```

Answer (score 0):

XD modules that access Gemfire, e.g., the gemfire source and gemfire sink use client-server configuration.

You have a remote cache server and the module is a client. Connecting via a locator requires all servers and clients in the grid to share the locator addresses. Assuming your Gemfire server installation already has one or more locators running, the module context should contain a [client-cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap:cache:client) configured with the same locator addresses as the remote cache server. If you are not familiar with Gemfire client-server topology, I suggest you review the [product documentation](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#topologies_and_comm/cs_configuration/setting_up_a_client_server_system.html) and get a simple stand alone example running against your cache server before attempting to deploy your XD modules.

Comment: Thanks you for response.  I install standalone gemfire 8.0.0 server, started locator,server,created region. I had configured spring.xml to configure gemfire.<cache><cache-server port=".."  <region name="regionName"><region-attributes refid="REPLICATE"></region-attributes></region></cache>,<gfe:cache id="client-cache" cache-xml-location="cache.xml" properties-ref="gemfire-props"/><gfe:pool id="my-pool" subscription-enabled="true"><gfe:locator host=".." port=".."/></gfe:pool><gfe:client-region id="regionName" name="regionName" cache-ref="client-cache"/>. Can you give sample clientconfiguration?